# MySQL: why could copying to tmp table be faster after optimizing table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, performance, optimization, indexing

We have a table with 130 000 records. A certain query (4 queries with some inner joins and unions) takes 0.13 seconds. Performance is ok. After a few hours we see that the same query takes 0.4-0.5 seconds to execute.

We do an optimize table and voila: the same query runs again in 0.13 seconds average.

Can it be that a table with many indexes loses it's performance which is restored by an optimize? (The time to update, delete, insert is good, so the indexes don't have much impact there) We have quite a few indexes on that table because we thought that an index on a column which is used to inner join on is required for speed. Is that wrong?

Example "Select * from A inner join B on A.column = b.id", we make an index on A.column.

PS: While testing, we disable the query cache

EDIT: profiling info with the details that are different, apparently after optimizing a table, copying to tmp table is quicker.

Bad performance:
**Copying To Tmp Table  244 ms**
Sending Data    40 µs
Optimizing  44 µs
Statistics  141 µs
Preparing   37 µs
Creating Tmp Table  45 µs
Executing   8 µs
**Copying To Tmp Table  213,6 ms**
Sending Data    44 µs
Optimizing  7 µs
Statistics  25 µs
Preparing   9 µs
Executing   6 µs

Good performance:
**Copying To Tmp Table  22,1 ms**
Sending Data    39 µs
Optimizing  33 µs
Statistics  105 µs
Preparing   33 µs
Creating Tmp Table  42 µs
Executing   11 µs
**Copying To Tmp Table  23,1 ms**
Sending Data    60 µs
Optimizing  11 µs
Statistics  15 µs
Preparing   15 µs
Executing   8 µs

Comment: Is it mysql or sql-server? disable query cache in production if your cache hit ratio is anything below %100

Comment: Have you looked into Profiling? [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html) .. Maybe you can index on other appropriate fields. As far as the degradation of performance for the query - I am not sure. See [this article](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28719/query-performance-degrades-with-time-and-use) for a related Q&A.

Comment: Thanks already! Will profile it if I see it degrades again and after the optimize and come back with more info!

Comment: Sure - let me know what happens.

Comment: I edited the question. Seems that copying to temp table goes from 22 ms to 244 ms. Huge difference. I don't get it, why would an optimize table 'interfere' with copying to tmp table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We "solved" the problem by forcing all sorting etcetera in the memory:

tmpdir = /dev/shm

The query now always run 0,1 second. It cost us some RAM but we have enough to trade it for speed.